# Torque wrenches of the same force but different head size

Tags: torque, buying

I am looking at two torque wrenches both are:

- same length
- same force

The ONLY difference is that one is 1/4 and the other is 3/8.

I know adaptors don't affect the accuracy but which one to get? Should I go big and adapt down or go small and adapt up if needed?

The main use is for changing bolts on a motorbike clutch.

Comment: Adaptors are a pain. Except for low torques, they can be unstable, and a tool that disassembles itself when try to you use it is useless.

Comment: @alephzero thank you for that; I i'm going to avoid the adapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you buy these things by their torque range and by the sockets you use. It helps to get an overview of the torque range you need in the future.

It also happens seldom that two wrenches with different socket sizes have the same torque range.

If both wrenches are, apart from the socket size, exactly the same, I'd get the size of most of my sockets.

Comment: This is the best answer I have received. Since my need is a clutch replacement, and that uses a 1/4  drive; I will get the 1/4 ratchet.

Incase anyone was wondering the two options where:

Teng 1492AGE
and
Teng 3892ag-E1